How to declare in a *.d.ts file an Iterable of two different types?
This is the javascript function I'm unsuccessfully trying to make vscode show autocomplete suggestions for the returned object:
const profile = (form, validation) =>
  Object.defineProperties(
    { form, validation },
    {
      0: { value: form },
      1: { value: validation },
      length: { value: 2 },
      [Symbol.iterator]: { value: Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator] },
      [Symbol.toStringTag]: { value: 'ValidationProfile' },
    },
  );

This is the *d.ts file for the returned object's type I was experimenting with. It's definitely wrong.:
import { Validation } from './validation';

export type ValidationProfile = typeof ValidationProfileAPI;

// !!! the returned object is not an array, just tried to make it work somehow
const ValidationProfileAPI: [HTMLFormElement, Validation];

declare namespace ValidationProfileAPI {
    let form: HTMLFormElement;
    let validation: Validation;
    interface iterator implements Iterable<HTMLFormElement|Validation> {}
}

I managed to find a similar problem here but I can't figure out how to adapt it for my case.
I will be grateful for any suggestions.
UPD
This is what worked out for me.
Based on this solution TypeScript interface with array destructuring
import { Validation } from './validation';

export interface ValidationProfile extends Iterable<HTMLFormElement | Validation> {
    form: HTMLFormElement;
    validation: Validation;
    [0]: HTMLFormElement;
    [1]: Validation;
}



Welcome to Stack Overflow! What's Validation? Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] where we can copy and paste it into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing. Right now all I see are errors unrelated to the question. If you can get it working in an online IDE like the TS playground, and then drop that code as plaintext here, it would be a lot easier for others to get started.

Why are you creating such a weird array-like value in the first place instead of just making it a real array? Object.freeze(Object.defineProperties([form, validation], { form: {get() { return this[0]; }}, validation: {get() { return this[1]; }}, [Symbol.toStringTag]: {value: 'ValidationProfile'} })) might be easier to handle

@jcalz, @Bergi Thank you. The solution from above TypeScript interface with array destructuring  helped. But instead of extending Array, I extended Iterable of union type: export interface ValidationProfile extends Iterable<HTMLFormElement | Validation> {     form: HTMLFormElement;     validation: Validation;     [0]: HTMLFormElement;     [1]: Validation; } I don't know if it is correct but it works. VSCode shows autocomplete for properties of variables which come from array destructuring.

@Bergi I was trying to resolve the dilemma in the first place whether It should be an Array with additional named properties or an Object with additional indexed properties. The latter seemed more straightforward. Indexed props won't show up in Object.keys(). It doesn't entail the whole bunch of Array's prototype methods, which are unnecessary in this case and might pollute autocomplete. So in case of Object, only what is needed is shown.
